# Particular generalized eigenvalue problem with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If the generalized eigenvalue problem is given by $A x = u Dx$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with two parameters, one, say $a$ for all the diagonal elements, except the last one, say $b$. How does the eigen-system change  by varying $a$ and $b$?
$$D = \begin{bmatrix}
a &   &   &   &   & \\
  & a &   &   &   & \\
  &   & a &   &   & \\
  &   &   & \ddots &   & \\
  &   &   &   & a  & \\
  &   &   &   &    & b
\end{bmatrix}$$